# JDBC too many connections - Connections are closed properly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I hate to bring up a question which is widely asked on the web, but I cant seem to solve it.
I´m closing all my Connections properly but the programm is throwing a "too many Connection exception"

here is my Connectionhelper

```
 public MySQLConnection() {
    try {

      // Datenbanktreiber für ODBC Schnittstellen laden.
      // Für verschiedene ODBC-Datenbanken muss dieser Treiber
      // nur einmal geladen werden.
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      // Verbindung zur ODBC-Datenbank 'sakila' herstellen.
      // Es wird die JDBC-ODBC-Brücke verwendet.
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":"
          + dbPort + "/" + database + "?" + "user=" + dbUser + "&"
          + "password=" + dbPassword);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("Treiber nicht gefunden");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println("Connect nicht moeglich"+e);
    }
  }

  public Connection getInstance()
  {

    if(conn == null)
      new MySQLConnection();
    return conn;
  }


  public final void close_multiple( final Connection con, final ArrayList<PreparedStatement> listPreparedstatments, final ArrayList<ResultSet> listResultsets )
  {
      try
      {
          if ( con != null && con.isClosed())
          {
              con.close();

          }
          for(PreparedStatement pstm : listPreparedstatments)
              if ( pstm != null && pstm.isClosed())
              {
                  pstm.close();
              }
          for(ResultSet rs : listResultsets){
              if ( rs != null && rs.isClosed())
              {
                  rs.close();
              }
          }

      }
      catch ( SQLException e )
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public final void close_single( final Connection con, final PreparedStatement stmt, final ResultSet rs )
  {
      try
      {
          if( con != null && con.isClosed())
          {
              con.close();
          }
          if ( stmt != null && stmt.isClosed())
          {
              stmt.close();
          }
          if ( rs != null && rs.isClosed())
          {

            rs.close();
          }

      }
      catch ( SQLException e )
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

And here are some sample codes

```
 public ArrayList<Product_Type> getProduct_Types() throws JSONException {
      conn = mysqlconnection.getInstance();
      Product_Type product_type;
      ArrayList<Product_Type> listProduct_Types = new ArrayList<Product_Type>();
      if(conn != null){
          //MYSQL Resultsets and Statements
          ResultSet rst_product_type=null;
          PreparedStatement pstmt_product_type=null;
          try{

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM `product_type`";
            pstmt_product_type = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rst_product_type = pstmt_product_type.executeQuery();

            while(rst_product_type.next()) { 
                product_type = new Product_Type();
                product_type.setProduct_Type_ID(rst_product_type.getInt("Product_Type_ID"));
                product_type.setProduct_Type_Name(rst_product_type.getString("Product_Type_Name")); 
                listProduct_Types.add(product_type);
            }
         } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Unable to connect to product_type Table.");
         } finally {
             mysqlconnection.close_single(conn, pstmt_product_type, rst_product_type);
         }
      }
      return listProduct_Types; 
  }

  public ArrayList<Product_Type> getProduct_Type_by_Manufacturer_ID(int manufacturer_id) throws JSONException, SQLException {
        conn = mysqlconnection.getInstance();
        Product_Type product_type;
        ArrayList<Product_Type> listProduct_Types = new ArrayList<Product_Type>();
        ArrayList<ResultSet> listResultsets = new ArrayList<ResultSet>();
        ArrayList<PreparedStatement> listPreparedstatments = new ArrayList<PreparedStatement>();

         if(conn != null){
             PreparedStatement pstmt_product_detail = null;
             PreparedStatement pstmt_product_type = null;

             ResultSet rst_product_type = null;
             ResultSet rst_product_detail = null;
             try{                       
                    String sql_product_detail = "SELECT DISTINCT(Product_Type_ID) FROM `product_details` WHERE Manufacturer_ID=?"; 
                    pstmt_product_detail = conn.prepareStatement(sql_product_detail);
                    pstmt_product_detail.setInt(1, manufacturer_id);
                    rst_product_detail = pstmt_product_detail.executeQuery();

                    while(rst_product_detail.next()) { 
                         String sql_product_type = "SELECT Product_Type_ID, Product_Type_Name FROM `product_type` WHERE Product_Type_ID=?";
                         pstmt_product_type = conn.prepareStatement(sql_product_type);
                         pstmt_product_type.setInt(1, rst_product_detail.getInt("Product_Type_ID"));
                         rst_product_type = pstmt_product_type.executeQuery();

                         while(rst_product_type.next()) { 
                             product_type = new Product_Type();
                             product_type.setProduct_Type_ID(rst_product_type.getInt("Product_Type_ID"));
                             product_type.setProduct_Type_Name(rst_product_type.getString("Product_Type_Name"));    
                             listProduct_Types.add(product_type);
                        }
                     }
                    listPreparedstatments.add(pstmt_product_type);
                    listPreparedstatments.add(pstmt_product_detail);
                    listResultsets.add(rst_product_detail);
                    listResultsets.add(rst_product_type);
             } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Unable to connect to pr Table.");
             } finally {
                 //Close MYSQL-Connection
                 mysqlconnection.close_multiple(conn, listPreparedstatments, listResultsets);
             }
         }

         return listProduct_Types;
  }
```

I dont get it where is the Problem? I also tried to increase the mysql max connections but it´s still not working

Comment: Aside from anything else, why are you creating a new instance of `MySQLConnection()` in an *instance* method... why don't you just create the connection there? I assume `conn` is a static variable, although you haven't shown it... this is really messy. (And your names don't follow Java naming conventions...)

Comment: yes thanks for your comment. i changed the code several times so its a little bit messy but i will change your mentioned points

Comment: Additionally... You don't need to keep checking the connection... move the connection into the try block and then close it when your done.

Comment: You'd be better off just using [driver manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) to handle the connection too.

Comment: You haven't needed the `Class.forName()` call since 2007.

Answer (score 4):

You are actually not closing the connections (and ResultSets and PreparedStatements) at all, the `con.close()` in this code will be called only if the connection is already closed:

```
if (con != null && con.isClosed()) {
    con.close();
}
```

It should probably be `!con.isClosed()`.

This seems to be the main problem. However there are also other problems in your code as mentioned by John Skeet in the question comment.

Comment: The same point applies to the other `if` conditions as well, for PreparedStatements and ResultSets.  I also think you'd probably want to close those things before closing the connection itself.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Java7 you can take advantage of [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which takes care of automatically closing resources (A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it). Moreover your code will be simplified(by removing lines where you are just checking and closing connection, statement, resultSet) , easy to read and maintain E.g.

```
try (Connection conn = datasource.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {// you can use all other autocloseable objects in try clause

 //your code here
 }
```

Comment: give u plus for mentioning try with resources